# Discord JS bot dont reply again

Tags: javascript, discord

if i have bot to reply to message
like

```
if (message.content == '1') {
  message.channel.send('2');
}
```

when member send 1 once again the bot is send 2 again
How do I make him reply only once and not reply again?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple flag.

```js
let flag = true;
if (message.content == '1' && flag == true) {
    message.channel.send('2');
    flag = false;
}
```

This will make the code only run once.